# Is there a multiscale analysis for field theories?

Tags: field-theory, path-integral, differential-equations, non-equilibrium

Consider a (zero dimensional) Gaussian field theory described by the dynamical action

$$S = \int_t \tilde{\phi}(t) \left[\partial_t \phi(t) + M(t) \phi(t)\right] - \gamma \tilde{\phi}(t)^2\, .$$

$\phi(t)$ and $\tilde{\phi}(t)$ are scalar fields. The mass, $M(t)$ is slowly time-dependent,

$$M(t) = M_0 + M_1(\Omega t) \, .$$

$M_0$ does not depend on time. $M_1(\tau)$ is not small, but $\Omega$ is very small so that $M_1(\Omega t)$ has a slow time-dependence. Then there are two time scales $t_1 = 1/M_0$ and $t_2 = 1/\Omega>>t_1$, which are very different. How do I construct an expansion in powers of $\Omega/M_0$ for the Green functions (two-point correlation functions) of my field theory?

I know about [multiscale analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-scale_analysis) for differential equations (see also [this](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387989310)), which looks very much like my problem. Presently I do not know how to apply this type of analysis to a field theory. Do you?